# CSS: Element Being Pushed Down

Tags: css, positioning

I have an issue where when the user inputs text into the textfield, the JavaScript that dynamically displays and writes how many chars he/she has left keeps pushing the wrapper that contains the button/links elements down a certain number of units. I want the button wrapper to stay fixed and not move when the JavaScript does it's thing. The screenshots below illustrate what is happening.

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Any general suggestions as to how you prevent this?

Comment: Screenshots are cool. Code is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you add the text below the textbox but you could give the element an initial `visibility` value of [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/visibility). It won't be shown but it will occupy space.

**Update:**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/VcxHK/)

You might not even need to hide the element beforehand. If you give it a fixed height and it is empty by default, it works as well.

Comment: There is no `display: hidden`. It is `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Changed it already (even before the downvote). Is this worth a downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Set the label to `position: absolute`.
This will cause the layout engine to ignore any space that it occupies.

Alternatively, you can set it to `visibility: hidden` when not in use.
This will cause it to always occupy space, even when hidden.
You can then adjust your layout accordingly to make it fit.

Answer (score 0):

Position the chars left text absolute.

Answer (score 0):

I see two straight forward ways of doing this:

1. Specify a fixed size for the element that will contain the message or the element containing the field and the message, so there is room for the message from the start.
2. Use absolute positioning for the message, so that it doesn't affect any other elements at all.